# Error in loading the image from master page to content page

Tags: asp.net

I have created an asp.net application with a master and a content page. My master page contains buttons and images which are also to be displayed in the content page. But I am only getting the buttons, but no images (images are present in both header and footer). Can you suggest a solution to this?

Comment: Where is the location of your images? Tell us and it may be solved?

Answer (score 1):

What are the URLs of your images? How are you linking to them? If you are calling them relative, and if your master page and your content pages are in different paths or path levels, your content pages might not be getting the correct URLs to the images.

Example:

If your master page is in "/MasterPage/master.master" and your content pages are in "/Pages/PageType1/page.aspx", and your master page has

```
<img src="../images/sample.jpg">
```

Your page content will be looking for the image in "/Pages/images/sample.jpg", which will be wrong.